# Emacs does not reference C's head files directly

Tags: elisp

When invoking C's API to write dynamic modules,

emacs does not reference C' head files directly but use

```
emacs_value Fmake_hash_table = env->intern(env, "make-hash-table")
emacs_value sth = env->funcall(env, Fmake_hash_table, 2, arg)
```

Why get it done in such a cumbersome way?

Comment: What did you have in mind as a less-cumbersome alternative?

Comment: I believe https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-02/msg00960.html covers the general motivations, in any case.